# Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I open a link in a new tab in the extension HTML.

E.g.

*clicks on icon*

*sees Google chrome window which has the window.html*

inside there are two links, one link to open a link in a new tab, other in the original tab.

I used window.location, doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this question has two upvotes, but anyway you can try using the [target](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_target.asp) attribute for anchor elements.

```
<a target="_blank" src="http://myFancyUrl">This is a link to a new tab</a>
```

However, it won't open in a new tab unless the user has the navigator configured that way (usually does).

Answer (score 4):

If the page is indeed in a google chrome extension, you can force the browser to open the page in a new tab using javascript (which you know is enabled sine you are a google chrome extension).

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://somewhere", selected:true});
```

Your extension will need the tabs permission.

See: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html